# Wordpress Comment Query with pagination resulting in 404

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to display a list of comments a user has made on his author page, with pagination links.

First I created a simple function in `functions.php` to get the author's number of comments.

```
function commentCount() {
    global $wpdb;
    $author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
    $count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' WHERE comment_author_email = "' . $author->user_email . '"');
    return $count;
}
```

Doing a `var_dump(commentCount())` in `author.php` returns the correct number of comments of that particular user which is 26.

Next, I created a custom query using `WP_Comment_Query()` to retrieve the author's comment content.

```
$comments_per_page = 10;

/*Count comments*/
$all_comments_approved = commentCount();

/*Get Current Page Var*/
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

/*How many comments offset*/
$offset = (($paged-1) * $comments_per_page) ;

/*Max number of pages*/
$max_num_pages = ceil( $all_comments_approved / $comments_per_page );

$args = array(
  'user_id' => $author->ID, // comments by this user only
  'status' => 'approve',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'number' => $comments_per_page,
  'offset' => $offset
);

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
  foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo $comment->comment_content . '<br>';
  }

  /*Set current page for pagination*/
  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

  /*Echo paginate links*/
  echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'current' => $current_page,
    'total' => $max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
                      'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
                      'end_size' => 2,
                      'mid-size' => 3
                     ));
} else {
  echo 'No comments found.';
}
```

The above code is placed in `author.php` and it retrieves the comments, and displays them 10 per day as `$comments_per_page` specifies. And I can see the pagination links at the end, I see 3 pages.

If I navigate to the second page, I see 10 other comments. However if I navigate to page 3, I get `404 Page Not Found`

So basically, I can only see 20 comments out of the 26.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: This is the HTML code that is being outputted by `paginate_links()`

```
<div class="">
    <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://localhost/sciencr/profile/jane-flegal/page/2/">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://localhost/sciencr/profile/jane-flegal/page/3/">3</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://localhost/sciencr/profile/jane-flegal/page/2/">Next »</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give me html code that echoes paginate_links() function?

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko I've updated my original code and added the HTML output.

Comment: Look at solution here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176347/pagination-returns-404-after-page-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research I came into this solution, which worked smoothly after some tweaking.

It was basically a pagination error because I had multiple pagination links on the same page. The solution from the link below works great.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/multiple-wp-query-loops-with-pagination